# Linear algebra Plane and line

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a plane with points: $ A = (-5, 1, 3), B = (-2, 6, -3), C = (-4, 3, 4)$

I also have a line with points: $ D = (-2, 7, 6), E = (-1, 8, -2)$

The vector equation form of the line:
$$
\left\{
   \begin{array}{c|}
      \begin{pmatrix}
        -2\\
         7\\
         6
      \end{pmatrix}
     + r         \begin{pmatrix}
         1\\
         1\\
         8
      \end{pmatrix}
\end{array}
r \in \Bbb R
\right.
$$

The vector equation form of the plane:
$$
\left\{
   \begin{array}{c|}
      \begin{pmatrix}
        -5\\
         1\\
         3
      \end{pmatrix}
     + s  
       \begin{pmatrix}
         3\\
         5\\
         -6
      \end{pmatrix}+t
    \begin{pmatrix}
         1\\
         2\\
         1
      \end{pmatrix}
\end{array}
s,t \in \Bbb R
\right.
$$

I am supposed to compute the intersection between these two.

What I know about intersection is that if I have a linear equation with no solution, then there is no intersection. If i have a Linear equation with one solution, then there is one intersection. If i have a linear equation with infinitely many solutions, then the line is contained within the plane.

I the answer is that the line is contained within the plane. I know the answer, but how is the solution squired is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We have that $\vec{x}$ lies in the intersection iff:

$\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
        -2\\
         7\\
         6
      \end{pmatrix}
     + r         \begin{pmatrix}
         1\\
         1\\
         8
      \end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
        -5\\
         1\\
         3
      \end{pmatrix}
     + s  
       \begin{pmatrix}
         3\\
         5\\
         -6
      \end{pmatrix}+t
    \begin{pmatrix}
         1\\
         2\\
         1
      \end{pmatrix}$.

This leads to: $$\begin{pmatrix}
        -2\\
         7\\
         6
      \end{pmatrix}
     + r         \begin{pmatrix}
         1\\
         1\\
         8
      \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        -5\\
         1\\
         3
      \end{pmatrix}
     + s  
       \begin{pmatrix}
         3\\
         5\\
         -6
      \end{pmatrix}+t
    \begin{pmatrix}
         1\\
         2\\
         1
      \end{pmatrix}$$ This is a system of 3 linear equations with 3 unknowns. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I actually got this part. But when i get here I don't know how I should set it up. Sorry :/

Comment: It might be helpful if you show your work, cause otherwise one can only guess what your problem is. Do you have problems to write this as 3 single equations? $$-2+r=-5+3s+t$$ $$7+r=1+5s+2t$$ $$6+8r=3-6s+1$$

Comment: In that logic, did you presume that the line is contained in the plane?`

Because I want to solve it as if I didn't know that.

Comment: No, all I'm looking for is for some $\vec{x}$ that lie in the intersection, not assuming anything at all.

Comment: will try to solve, that. Brb with my results.

Comment: Got it to S = (2 + 8r)/6, t = 2 - 3r
and i applied that in the first equation and got 0 = 0, which means that there is an infinite amount of solutions. 

Was that correct?

Comment: That sounds about right, yes. So you know that you have infinite many $\vec{x}$ that lie in the intersection...what do you get from this?

Comment: That the line is contained within the plane!

Thank you very much!

Comment: @user135839 You're welcome. If you want to, you can accept this answer as helpful in finding the solution to your problem.